# Show and hide text of different posts

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have several posts each of them composed of three parts : a title, a username/date and a body. What I want to do is to show the body when I click on either the title or the username/date and hide it if I click on it again. What I've done so far works but not as expected because when I have two or more posts, it only shows the body of the last post even if I click on another post than the last one. So my goal is only to show the hidden text body corresponding to the post I'm clicking on. Here is my code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header %}
  <h1>{% block title %}Test page{% endblock %}</h1>
  <a class="action" href="{{ url_for('main_page.create') }}">New</a>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  {% for post in posts %}
    <article class="post">
      <header>

        <script language="JavaScript">
          function showhide(newpost)
          {var div = document.getElementById(newpost);
            if (div.style.display !== "block")
               {div.style.display = "block";}
            else {div.style.display = "none";}}
        </script>

        <div onclick="showhide('newpost')">
          <h1>{{ post['title'] }}</h1>
          <div class="about">by {{ post['username'] }} on {{ post['created'].strftime('%d-%m-%Y') }}</div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div id="newpost">
        <p class="body">{{ post['body'] }}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    {% if not loop.last %}
      <hr>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Of course I looked for a solution as much as I could but I'm kind of stuck plus I'm a complete beginner in HTML/JS/CSS. And one last thing, I'm currently using Python's framework Flask. Thank you by advance.

Comment: You can't repeat element ID's in a page. They are unique by definition

Comment: So what would be the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give each of your posts a unique `id` for your approach to work.

Change your code to

```html
<div id="{{post_id}}">
    <p class="body">{{ post['body'] }}</p
</div>
```

where `post_id` is that post's unique `id` e.g. its `id` in the database you are using that you pass to the template in your view. Then, change the call to the `onclick` event handler to

```html
<div onclick="showhide('{{post_id}}')">
```

If you don't have a unique `id` you can also use the for loop's index: replace all `post_id` instances above with `loop.index`. See Jinja's [`for` loop docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/?highlight=loop%20index#for) for more information.

Comment: Awesome man ! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: I'm happy it solved the problem! Can you accept the answer so others can find it as well?